# How can I prevent endless builds using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

There are conditions where Eclipse builds Codename One projects endlessly.

This is always the case when "Refresh using native hooks or polling" is activated for the workspace.

I am wondering why this is happening. Eclipses automatic build tracks changes in source folders and automaticalls builds when changes occur.

Any idea what causes those endless builds with Codename One projects?

Adding a resource filter in the dist-folders properties is to no avail.

[image: Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace]

Comment: Is it possible that any change in any project triggers build for all the Codename One projects?

Answer (score 0):

Our build process generates files since it uses Ant, it replaces existing project files (especially if you use the new GUI builder) so this is probably throwing Eclipse for a spin which re-runs the build which regenerates the files resulting in endless loop.

I'd love to improve building on Eclipse but I'm not really sure how we can do that in a way that still works well with the whole build process.

Comment: Since Ant is used for building setting "Refresh using native hooks or polling" would be a good thing to do. The build should only be triggered by changes to sources and everything should be working nicely. So why is the build triggered by any changes?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what is triggering this, I think there are calls back and forth to refresh that relate to updating changes from our external tools. The problem is that this is a very delicate balance and I'm a bit timid about changing it as it might have a far reaching effect.